# How to handle many to many relationships in Graph database?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

How to model `Many-to-Many` relationship in Graph databases (Property graph database)

In the below picture, Company/creditor files their claim to court when the borrower goes bankrupt and there will be an authorised representative for the each company/creditor to the case. How to model this scenario ?

Find who is representative of given creditor? Trick is creditor can have multiple claim on multiple case and multiple authorized representative.

Any suggestion ? If possible in `Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin` way of handling.

[image: Many to Many Relationship]

Comment: In neo4j graph DB this is easy to handle. It is built for such cases

Comment: Can you explain how? or share any documents..

Comment: I'm not quite clear what  you are asking. Many to many can be as simple as parallel edges.

Comment: Parallel edge helps on many to many. However I am not able to solve this scenario. Is it good practice to make edge label as dynamic ?

Comment: That depends on your data and you want to achieve. Generally speaking you can use a label or a property.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you are representing here, but if the edge is `for case 2` it is better to connect `Representative` with the case directly. Maybe the company can also be connected to the case, but not as a middleman...

Comment: What kind of queries do you want to run here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, one option is to connect the `Representative` directly to the `Case`. This will eliminate the need to add a dynamic label (Although we don't know what you want to query yet).

On neo4j, it can be modeled like this:

```
MERGE (a:Representative {key: 1})
MERGE (b:Representative {key: 2})
MERGE (c:Representative {key: 3})
MERGE (d:Company{key: 1})
MERGE (e:Company{key: 2})
MERGE (f:Case{key: 1})
MERGE (g:Case{key: 2})

MERGE (a)-[:CASE]-(f)
MERGE (b)-[:CASE]-(g)
MERGE (c)-[:CASE]-(g)
MERGE (d)-[:CREDITOR]-(f)
MERGE (d)-[:CREDITOR]-(g)
MERGE (e)-[:CREDITOR]-(g)
MERGE (a)-[:CONTACT]-(d)
MERGE (b)-[:CONTACT]-(d)
MERGE (c)-[:CONTACT]-(e)
```

And look like this:
[image: graph]